# Is it possible to encrypt a file using both AES-256 cipher, password and keyfile using OpenSSL?

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

Is it possible to encrypt a file using both AES-256 cipher, password and keyfile using OpenSSL?

I want to encrypt a file using OpenSSL.

After hours of testing I have found a command which may partially do what I want:

`openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in input.txt -out output.txt`

When I run the command above I am prompted for a password which is desirable in this scenario.

I am wondering if and how I can use the command above both with a password and a keyfile. I.e. a keyfile is used to encrypt the input.txt file and a password is also used. I have tested the `-inkey` flag already but it does not seem to work.

OS: Linux (custom)

Comment: `-pass file:your_keyfilename -pass:yourpassword`
https://superuser.com/questions/724986/how-to-use-password-argument-in-via-command-line-to-openssl-for-decryption

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in input.txt -out output.txt -pass file:user.key generates this error message: Error reading password from BIO
Error getting password. If I add -pass:password at the end I also get an error message.

Comment: `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in input.txt -out output.txt -pass file:user.key -pass pass:password`

Comment: I made one test and it may work. Will test again as soon as possible. But is it possible to make openssl prompt for the password instead?

Comment: `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in qq.html -out qq.enc -pass file:user.key -pass stdin`    ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Whatever you do, don't try specifying multiple `-pass` arguments as @mootmoot suggests in the comments. Only the latest applies, as can be trivially seen by:

```
echo test | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass file:key -pass pass:password | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass pass:password
```

Assuming you're trying to require both the password and the keyfile to decrypt, the easiest way would be to simply chain them, though this will result in a slight size increase:

```
$ echo test | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass file:key >testout
enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
Verifying - enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:

$ <testout openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass file:key | openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
test
```

You should be aware though that the key derivation `openssl enc` uses is quite terrible. 0.9.8 defaults to MD5, and while it lets you select another hash, it only allows one round of `hash(password || salt)`. 1.1.0 changes the default hash to SHA256, but it still only allows a single round, so the improvement is very minor.

I've also seen this [quote](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Re-Accessing-PBKDF2-from-command-line-td25835.html#a25837) from an openssl developer referenced a few times:

> At the end of the day, OpenSSL is a *library*, not an end-user product, 
>   and enc(1) and friends are developer utilities and "demo" tools.

It's from 2009, so I don't know how much that's changed since then (I believe the `cms` utility is ok), but I would recommend avoiding `enc` if possible.

Comment: You can specify `-md sha1` or something of that sort on the older systems that use MD5 by default. It's still pretty terrible though since there's no slow KDF.

Comment: Versions back at least to 0.9.8 allow selecting the hash for password-based derivation, but the _default_ is md5 through 1.0.2 versus sha256 in 1.1.0 (and soon 1.1.1). In either/any case it's only one iteration, which is the real problem, as you correctly say.

Comment: @forest, dave_thompson_085 You're both correct, not sure why I missed that. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Version 1.1.1 has the `iter` option, which can be used to specify the number of sha256 iterations to use in the pbkdf2 key derivation.  See https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-enc.html.